# running c++ code inside sublime text 2 shows strange message?

Tags: c++, sublimetext2

> [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified [cmd:  [u'bash',
>   u'-c', u"g++ 'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\Average' -o
>   'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2/Average' && 'C:\Program
>   Files\Sublime Text 2/Average'"]] [dir:  C:\Program Files\Sublime Text
>   2] [path:
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\TCWIN45\BIN]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you don't have bash or g++. Since you are on windows that's logical. Bash is something that windows don't include by default. You probably need the unix tools that microsoft provides on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'run' C++ code in Sublime Text 2. You *can* invoke make (and arbitrary other programs) from it though. This is trying to run bash and g++, both of which aren't usually part of a windows environment.